# Convert consecutive numbers in a R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with consecutive values, is it possible to make = 0 the numbers after 1s?

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0),
  b = c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0),
  c = c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0))
```

like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ +(.x == 1 & lag(.x, default = 0) != 1)))
```

output

```r
   a b c
1  0 0 1
2  0 0 0
3  0 1 0
4  0 0 0
5  1 0 0
6  0 0 0
7  0 0 0
8  0 0 1
9  0 0 0
10 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I see that the first method eliminates everything that is after, even what is not consecutive... es (0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1) turns in (0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)

Comment: My bad! did not see that. check edt

Answer (score 2):

Applying `diff` function may be another altarnative with `BaseR`,

```
out <- rbind(df[1,],apply(df,2,diff))
out[out!=1] <- 0
```

gives,

```
#   a b c
#1  0 0 1
#2  0 0 0
#3  0 1 0
#4  0 0 0
#5  1 0 0
#6  0 0 0
#7  0 0 0
#8  0 0 1
#9  0 0 0
#10 0 0 0
```

Comment: Note that `df` is vectorized. No need for `apply`: `rbind(df[1,], diff(as.matrix(df))>0)`

Answer (score 1):

We keep a `1` only if it is preceded by a `0` (a `1` on the first row will always be kept). We can do this by multiplying all but the first row by the negation of all but the last row (in R, we use negative indices to *exclude* an index).

```
df[-1,] <- df[-1,]*!df[-nrow(df),]
df
#>    a b c
#> 1  0 0 1
#> 2  0 0 0
#> 3  0 1 0
#> 4  0 0 0
#> 5  1 0 0
#> 6  0 0 0
#> 7  0 0 0
#> 8  0 0 1
#> 9  0 0 0
#> 10 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

We load `data.table` for the use of `shift()`.

```
library(data.table)
df[] <- lapply(df, \(x) replace(x, shift(x, fill = 0) == 1, 0))
df
#    a b c
# 1  0 0 1
# 2  0 0 0
# 3  0 1 0
# 4  0 0 0
# 5  1 0 0
# 6  0 0 0
# 7  0 0 0
# 8  0 0 1
# 9  0 0 0
# 10 0 0 0
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: @Chris If there is something unclear I'm happy to explain.